# A song using the same melody as part of the chorus of "Still Breathing" by "Mayday Parade"

Tags: identify-this-song, rock

The chorus for *Still Breathing* by *Mayday Parade* has the following lines:

> 'Cause I'm standing here alone
>   Trying to make this life my own

Link: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEw3aw5huc0)

Listen to that part and pay attention to the melody of the vocals, the groove of the drums and the overall "epic" sound of the music.

I *swear to God* there is another song that has these traits, but for the life of me I can't remember what it is, and it's driving me crazy. I've tried all the Googling I can think of.

It has the same vocal melody (except for the second syllable of "alone") and has a very similar feel overall. I believe it was sung by a male vocalist, and was probably on the radio some time between 2000 and 2010.

If anyone knows the song I'm talking about, I'd appreciate being able to put this question to rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so five months later and I thought about this again and realized that the song I was think of was a DragonForce song. So I listened to every one of their songs I own, and I found it: Black Winter Night. Specifically the ending of the chorus. Same chord progression and vocal melody (from what I can hear).
[Here's the song on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vE5LP0keEE)